# How to correct darkening damage to and old photograph?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, restoration

This is a precious family photo, but it was stuck to the glass, resulting in this weird scan, which is all I have to work with. I can't figure out how to "reveal" the grandmother - I'm sure there's enough pixel data under the damage to work with, but everything I tried added color or altered the color, obscuring her more.

Is there a way to "erase" the blot while leaving the underlying color and details intact?

[image]

Comment: if no one gives you a way to do it yourself, you could try to ask on the Photoshop Requests subreddit? https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/
Generally speaking they are quite helpful.

Comment: Hi NanBarnes, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I took the liberty to edit it slightly for legibility and a bit of formality (we're not a forum, so texts like 'thanks in advance' are discouraged, better left to the comments). If I ended up butchering it beyond your recognition, feel free to [edit] things back to something that reflects your intention better. In any case, happy to have you! Have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to know more about what makes this site tick.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's going to take rather a lot of manual painting to fix damage like that.  To begin the process of repairing it, you need to reduce the effect of the damage, since I don't think it will be possible to remove it completely in one step.

One method might be to create a curves adjustment layer, fill the mask black, and paint in the curves adjustment using white on the mask.

For example:

[image]

Obviously this is only a first step.

Once the majority of the damage has been removed, you could create a new layer - a copy of the visible layers (using Shift+Ctrl+E), and then begin to do more detailed repairs on that, perhaps using the Spot Healing brush.

For example:

[image]

And finally, a bit of Dodging to remove leftover dark areas, and some cloning, to clean up.

[image]